# Incremental clusterig

Tags: string, cluster-analysis

please suggest some way for efficient incremental clustering. I am trying to put similar strings to one group. comparing with each other is not efficient. what i have thought is to check the each input string with the cluster representative( this means there is one representative pattern for strings in that cluster so that the new string can be compared to that only). So, anything to start with so that the nearly similar strings in a cluster can be represented by one universal pattern(may be) with highest possible accuracy. In this way the new input are just compared with cluster representative and the kept into it if found similar.  The number of cluster and input are not fixed...strings are streaming and may be of any pattern length.

I hope i was clear. Just help me with some term to get going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the part of the problem that is giving you difficulty is finding a representative pattern to use for each cluster.

The usual way to do clustering of strings is to treat them as vectors and use cosine similarity as the distance measure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_distance

When the strings in the cluster are represented as vectors, then I think the center of the cluster is just the sum of the normalized vectors.  Use this sum as the representative to compare each new string against.